# Java - send HTTP POST request without downloading all the content

Tags: java, http, post, response

Is it possible to send HTTP POST request to a webserver and retrieve just headers of response or read just few bytes of the body, so the rest won't be downloaded at all (so it won't consume traffic)? If yes, how?

I know that there is a HEAD method for this, but I need to achieve it by POST method .. well, I am not sure if I need the POST method, I just need to post the data. Maybe if the webserver isn't secured well enough (it doesn't check what method it's used - it's just directly access the post data), is it possible to send "post data" by HEAD request?

Comment: You could directly send the POST method, and use your java client to only read the header content. If you wont touch the response body, it won't downloaded.

Comment: According to my traffic log, it's downloaded even if i don't touch the body. e.g. when I want to just check some header value (HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(), URLConnection.getContentLength() ...),  it downloads full response

Comment: I think if you read your response header ASAP, then close your response immediately after reading. Your response content won't fully downloaded. Of cause, your client will try to download as much as it can before you close your response. But if you content is big enough, this way should save your bandwidth.

Comment: And how is that possible in Java?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in HTTP mechanism for this, and HTTP HEAD requests do not allow content in the body. If however you are the one writing the server code then anything is possible.

If this is the case, I would suggest a URL parameter that triggers this behavior.  For example:

```
POST /myURL - This would return the whole response

POST /myURL?body=minimal - Returns the reduced size response that you are looking for.
```

And you would have to code your server method to construct and return the appropriate response based on the URL parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I don't have access to server code I need to send request to, but thanks for idea